# How to add an object field in a Django model

Tags: django, object, model, nested, field

I would like to have a field that works as an object for one of my models, but without needing to reference it using a ForeignKey.

What I'm looking for is something like the field *pressure* here:

```json
{
    "professional": "d83876a6-69eb-4946-a0f7-56fd39cbd6a8",
    "observations": "Update",
    "date": "2022-03-22T21:45:37Z",
    "pressure": {
       "systolic_pressure": 0,
       "diastolic_pressure": 0
    }
}
```

I have searched a lot, but haven't found how to add a field like that one, and how to configure the model/serializer/view to be able to create/read/update/delete it.

Comment: Is a JSON field what you are after? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield I think a FK relation would be far easier as it fits into other Django features nicely, why do you not want to use one?

Comment: Not a JSON field but a nested model, in the example shown before, the field pressure would have 2 sub-fields that are integers.
I don't want to make it a FK relation because it would be used only on this model, and having it as a FK relation would complicate things like creating or updating the field.

Comment: A nested model is one that refers to itself, which yours isn't. If you don't want JSON or a FK then remove the nesting and have `systolic_pressure` and `diastolic_pressure` as ordinary fields. If you want to group them then add a method to your model like `def get_pressure(self): return self.systolic_pressure, self.diastolic_pressure`